# Convert const char** to void*?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-c++, gcc

Consider this code:

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Foo()
{
  const char ** caps = malloc( sizeof( char * ) );
  memset( caps, 0, sizeof( char * ) );
}
```

Compiles fine with gcc 4.9.2 -pedantic but cl 18 (the one from VS2013) with default options says `warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers` on the memset line.

Now `caps` is a pointer to a pointer to const char? So the pointer itself is not const hence it should convert to`void*` without problems, I think, but cl seems to automatically make `const void*` from it which generates the warning. Is that a correct explanation of what is going on? And this is non-standard behaviour, right?

Comment: I'd say probably a MS compiler bug. Although code like this makes my hair stand up, it's technically perfectly legal from what I can tell...

Comment: FWIW, clang (3.4.1) in pedantic mode also thinks your code is fine.

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403713/why-does-visual-c-warn-on-implicit-cast-from-const-void-to-void-in-c-but

Comment: @mafso good catch, that's exactly this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is overzealous (read as: compiler bug).

`const char** caps` means that `caps` is a pointer (which is not constant) to a different pointer (which is not constant either) to a `char` which is constant. That is, you promise not to modify that `char` via indirections that go over `caps`.
This means that you formally make the following contract with the compiler:

1. You are allowed to change `caps`.
2. You are allowed to change `*caps` (the `char*` that `caps` points to).
3. You are **not** allowed to change `**caps` (the `char` that `*caps` points to (which `caps` points to)) *via this chain pointers*.
4. Nothing is said about anyone else (e.g. aliasing pointers) changing the value of that character.

   const char **caps = malloc( sizeof( char * ) );

initializes `caps` with a value, which is legal. In case `malloc` fails, this value is a null pointer, but this, too, is generally perfectly legal from the point of view of the language (though it would cause the following `memset` to crash). In C++ you would be required to explicitly cast the `void*` returned by `malloc`, but C allows that kind of thing just fine.

```
memset(caps, 0, sizeof(char*));
```

makes my hair stand up (me being a C++ programmer), but it's nevertheless a perfectly legal thing from the point of view of the C language.
What it does is overwrite the so far allocated but uninitialized (and pointed-to by `caps`) block of memory which contains the second pointer with a number of zero bytes equal to the size of a pointer (a `char` pointer, as it happens).

The library function `memset`, which takes a non-const `void*`, simply fills the number of bytes you ask (here `sizeof(char*)`) with the value you provide (here: zero). It does not, and does not need to care, about the contract that you made with the compiler. But even so, it isn't violating any rules. It overwrites the pointer, *not* the pointed-to constant value.
Yes, it writes a couple of `char` values into something that *isn't* an array of `char`s (which is why my hair stands up), but well... that's... *legal*. It's just what `memset` is supposed to do, after all, and it will most probably "work as expected". It will set the pointer to a zero bit pattern, which -- except on some very rare exotic architectures -- corresponds to a null pointer.

At no point was the memory location `**caps` changed (or even accessed), so all of this is perfectly legal, you did not break any of your promises.

The warning is therefore wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms what I thought already. I didn't find how to search MS connect for bug reports so just filed a new one - hopefully this will get fixed once: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1184080/warning-c4090-incorrectly-issued-for-conversion-from-const-char-to-void

Answer (score -3):

You cannot cast a pointer to constant (`const X *`) to a `void *`: that would discard its `const` qualifier.

`memset` needs to modify those data, that is why it needs a `void *` parameter and not a `const void *` parameter.

Comment: I think you missed the point.  It's not `const X*` but rather `const X**`. `memset` would not be modifying the part intended to be `const`.

Comment: But, this is not a pointer to constant. It is a pointer to pointer to constant. This _should_ compile fine. With `const char**` you make the promise that you will not modify the `char` that the pointer that you point to points at via this pointer. This isn't happening when `memset` modifies the pointer.

Comment: It does not matter how many **** you put. It is still a pointer to something constant, and memset cannot modify it. Again, you cannot implicitly cast a const T * to a void *. Event if T is, in this case, char *.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 actually, it *does* matter how many levels of indirection is used.

Comment: it does not matter to the memset, which does see only the last one

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 nope, that's wrong. it seems you are seriously mistaken about how pointer typing works.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 There's a huge difference.  Given `const char* p = "foo"; const char** pp = &p;`, then `memset(p, ...)` is illegal because it's trying to modify the `const char` that `p` points to.  It's equivalent to `*p = '\0'`.  On the other hand, `memset(pp, ...)` should be perfectly fine because it's modifying *the pointer-to-const* that `pp` points to (note that the pointer itself is not `const`); it's equivalent to `*pp = NULL`.  It's just making `pp` point to something else, not modifying the `const` data.

Comment: `memset` does not see any `const` at all. It sees a `void*` which is non-const, and it fills `sizeof(pointer)` bytes with `(char) 0x00` although the pointed-to memory isn't even of type `char` from your point of view! Alas, `memset` doesn't (and doesn't need to) care. But the verdict about the type remains. This is a non-constant pointer to a different non-constant pointer (which is being overwritten, and legally so) to a `char` that is constant.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: _Again, you cannot implicitly cast a `const T *` to a `void *`_ -- yes. _Even if `T` is, in this case, `char *`._ -- no. Substituting `T` with `char *` in `const T *` yields `char *const *`; `const char **` is not of the form `const T *`.

Answer (score -3):

The way you wrote it, the const refers to the char, not to the pointer. Obviously, it makes little sense to allocate memory only to declare that it will never be modified (which means, it will never be initialized).

If you want the pointer itself to be const, you should write:

```
char ** const caps
```

You can also make the second pointer const, but that makes no more sense than making the char const.

Comment: stjin is allocating memory for a pointer-to-`const char`; that pointer itself is *not* `const` and can be given the address of something that is meant to be `const`.  That usage makes sense to me.