# MSVC const correctness : spurious C4090 warning

Tags: c, pointers, visual-c++, constants

MSVC emits warning [C4090](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4090?view=vs-2019) about const correctness while both GCC and Clang accept it : [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3J354g).

```c
void dummy(void)
{
    int i[42];
    int *pi[42];
    int const *pci[42];
    memset(i, 0, sizeof i);
    memset(pi, 0, sizeof pi);
    memset(pci, 0, sizeof pci); // warning C4090: 'function': different 'const' qualifiers
}
```

It seems MSVC treats `pci` as constant when it's not.

This bug is apparently [awfully old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403713/why-does-visual-c-warn-on-implicit-cast-from-const-void-to-void-in-c-but). Any idea how to fix this without turning [C4090](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4090?view=vs-2019) off ?

Comment: I'd just drop the `const`, which looks pretty useless to me here.

Comment: Apparently MSVC is being plain bad. It gives the very same warning for `int const pci[42];`. Maybe the compiler can't tell the difference between an array of integers and an array of pointers...

Comment: @Lundin False positives are annoying but I'd rather walk around compiler defects and be warned about actual undefined behavior.

Comment: @diapir Rather, you should stop using a compiler which doesn't fix 10 year old bugs. When it comes to PC compilers, there's a lot of other options.

Comment: casting `pci` to a `void*` should suppress the warning - `memset((void*)pci, 0, sizeof pci);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable this warning right before the line which invokes it and restore it back afterwards https://godbolt.org/z/W-XR-Q:

```
#include <string.h>

void dummy(void)
{
    int i[42];
    int *pi[42];
    const int *pci[42];

    memset(i, 0, sizeof i);
    memset(pi, 0, sizeof pi);

#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4090)
    memset(pci, 0, sizeof pci); // NO warning C4090
#pragma warning( pop ) 
}
```

Comment: Or just go with `#pragma warning( disable : 4090)` project-wide. This warning is obviously broken and can't be trusted.

Comment: I went with `#pragma warning(suppress : 4090)` which disables the warning on the next line. Cheers.